# RabbitMq bunny gem vs sneakers

Tags: rabbitmq, bunny

I am new to RabbitMq. We are evaluating it for production use with rails app, currently for background mailing system. RabbitMq tutorial presents [bunny](http://rubybunny.info/) gem. On it's other gem list, there is also [sneakers](http://jondot.github.io/sneakers/blog/) gem.

It would be useful to know, what are the difference between them, and which one is more useful to create a simple background mailing system ?

Comment: I would also like to know.  As far as I can tell bunny runs a subscription receive block in it's own thread.  Sneakers uses bunny internally and runs a worker in it's own thread.

Answer (score 6):

Bunny is your RabbitMQ connection wrapper. Send, receive, subscribe, etc.

Sneakers is a framework for a worker-centric approach. It uses Bunny to wrap its connections. You'd use Sneakers if you needed background processing in a Rails application or if you had different worker classes and wanted to standardize your approach.

Comment: I think both of them supply both functionalities, publish and process. They have api's for publish and pull/subscribe to jobs. In Bunny for example I did both.

Comment: You're totally right. I only started playing with it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What is the right way to spawn the 'listener' process? The one that pulls items from the queue?